# Regular Expression For Parsing JSON Objects

Tags: regex

I have a Json file containing text as such:

```
{
    title1: {
        x: "abc",
        y: "def"
    } ,

    title2:{
        x: "{{abc}}",
        y: "{{def}}"
    },
}
```

I want to first get the title1 title2 ,... groups. And after that, for each group, I want to get the x:..., y:... parts. I try to do this in two steps. For the first step, I used the following regexp:

```
[\s\S]*:\s*{(((?!}\s*,)[\s\S])*)
```

I am trying to say that find `:` followed by optional white space and then `{`. Then, continue until you see `}` followed by optional whitespace and `,`. But it finds the whole text as a match instead of title1 and title2 parts separately. What is wrong with it?

Comment: It might be easier to write an own JSON parser. Or even easier to use an existing one. Any particular reason you are trying to do it with regular expressions?

Comment: A couple quick notes. First, the text in your question is _not_ JSON. Second, assuming you do get JSON, you _can't_ parse JSON with a regular expression (due to arbitrarily nested constructs) so you should use your language's built in JSON parser. All major languages have them. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, this expression,

```
(\S+):\s*{\s*(((\S+):\s*"{*([^"{}]*)}*"\s*,?\s*)+)}
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/twnt1x/1/)

or:

```
(\S+):\s*{\s*(((\S+):\s*"{{0,2}([^"{}]*)}{0,2}"\s*,?\s*)+)}
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/oAKWmS/1/)

with bounded quantifier might be somewhat closer to what you have in mind.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/twnt1x/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/twnt1x/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: How can I make this one as a full match:     title1: {
        x: "abc",
        y: "def"
    } ,

Comment: Is there a way to use  https://regex101.com/r/ll3aFL/1/ but take  x: "abc",
        y: "def" together as the group?

Comment: I would like to accept your last solution if you could post it in your original answer.